# Filtering a complete date in django?

Tags: python, django, filter, date, django-queryset

There are several filter methods for dates (year,month,day). If I want to match a full date, say 2008/10/18, is there a better way than this:

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2008).filter(pub_date__month=10).filter(pub_date__day=18)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about using a [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object. For example:

```
from datetime import datetime
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date=datetime(2008, 10, 18))
```